# React Bootstrap form button inline

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

Any ways to add something like

[image: this]

(inline search form) in bootstrap?

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
</form>
```

using React-Bootstrap:

```js
<Form inline>
  <Button variant="outline-success"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></Button>
  <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" className="mr-sm-2" />
</Form>
```

> The icon from [fontawesome](http://fontawesome.io/icons/) library

Comment: better than before! but when I go in mobile view the button gose under the form yet